# A Halloween Chess Puzzle

Tags: no-computers, chess, seasonal

Halloween is finally here, so I thought I'd do a theme puzzle! I love chess, and I wanted to do a chess puzzle... so...

> [image]
>
> (It kind of looks like a jack-o-lantern, okay?)
>
> Black to move and mate in 5!
>
> No trickery here, just a normal chess puzzle.

Comment: Impressive picture!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty easy:

> 1... Rxb2+ 2. Ka1 Rd2+ 3. Kb1 Qe4+ 4. Nd3 Qxd3+ 5. Bc2 Qxc2#

Comment: A fancier way to do it is 4.....Rxd1+ 5. Ka2 Ra1# ;)

Comment: I didn't see that, and btw, did you intend to make the position look like a gift box with a handle?!

Comment: @WaisKamal: Given the OP said "It kind of looks like a jack-o-lantern" in the post that is a harsh put down! ;-) (joking, of course incase the ;-) isn't clear enough). The "handle" is the pumpkin stalk, the square is the border of the pumpkin and the pieces inside are the face.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know what a jack-o-lantern meant so I completely ignored it :)

Answer (score 5):

No idea about the puzzle but something spooky is definitely going on:

1. Black's pawns cannot get into that position without capturing some of White's pieces, but all White's pieces are on the board.
2. Similarly, White's pawn structure requires several captures (min 6) but Black retains all their pieces except one bishop.
3. Black has 17 pieces!

Are captured pieces/promoted pawns returning from beyond the board?

Comment: The puzzle wasn't intended to be a normally legal position. (also, one thing you may (or may not) have missed is that Black has 4 knights as well.

Comment: I can't imagine someone seeing this cornered black king and thinking of capturing pawns...